# In Bash, what is the string replacement pattern to remove any number of leading hyphens?

Tags: regex, bash, replace

This strips out any number of the leading hyphens:

```
§ echo '--nom-nom' | perl -pe 's|^-+||' 
nom-nom
```

**What should the replacement pattern look like if I want to use bash string replacement to do the same?** This does not work:

```
§ a=--nom-nom; a="${a/^-+/}"; echo $a
--nom-nom
```

Replacing all hyphens works, but that is not what I want:

```
§ a=--nom-nom; a="${a//-/}"; echo $a
nomnom
```

Comment: `a=--nom-nom; a=${a##--}; echo $a` works for this case. Ha, actually, even less code, `a=$(a#--}`. ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If shell option `extglob` is set, you can use an [extended pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-pattern-matching)

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a=--nom-nom; a="${a##*(-)}"; echo $a
nom-nom
```

If you don't want to always enable `extglob`, you can use a subshell to temporarily set it:

```
$ shopt -u extglob
$ a=--nom-nom; a=$(shopt -s extglob; echo "${a##*(-)}"); echo $a
```

`${var##*(-)}` uses the "remove longest matching prefix" replacement. You could also use `${var/#*(-)/}`; in this context, the `#` forces the match to be initial. In both cases, `*(pattern)` means "nothing or any number of repetitions of 'pattern'", similar to regex syntax except that the `*` comes first and the parentheses are required.

If you want to use regular expressions, you can use the [`expr` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html):

```
$ expr "$a" : '-*\(.*\)'
nom-nom
```

Note that this is *not* a bash built-in. But it is [required by Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html). It always uses Posix Basic Regular Expressions, which is why the capture parentheses need to be backslashed. (As noted in the documentation, it is expected that there will be precisely one capture group in the regex.)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture what you want vs eliminate what you don't want with a Bash regex:

```
$ s='--nom-nom' 
$ [[ $s =~ ^-*(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
nom-nom
```